# Application error when deploying to Worklight Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

I'm using Worklight Studio 6.2, WebSphere Application Server 8.5 Liberty Profile and Worklight Server. Using IBM DB2, and a remote server where i've installed all this stuff.

When i deploy an app to the server that's what i get.

```
Application Error
SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized:422'
javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver not found in Worklight platform or project /app1
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:422)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:127)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at [internal classes]
```

Dunno what could be, hope you can help me :S

Thanks

Comment: add your jar inside your <Project>.war project itself. That should do a trick

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Class org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver not found in Worklight platform or project /app1" effectively means that there is a problem with the data source definition, for the data source with JNDI name "app1/jdbc/WorklightDS" or "app1/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS". See the [Worklight documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_db2_manually.html?lang=en) for how to define these data sources.

Comment: In addition, since 6.1.0 this error does not appear on production environment. The only way you can face it is to take the worklight-jee-library.jar from the studio and use it on an external server which doesn't have hsql drivers

Comment: I also get same error, previously I can find the HsqlDB.jar at worklight deployment server project folder, but after I removed the project and related server instance and restart/rebuild workspace, the  driver jar disappeared, I expect it is re-generated by worklight studio again just like first time I found it. But I don't know how to get it appeared.